# Descriptors in global scope?

Tags: python, scope, descriptor

The [descriptor protocol](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors) in Python 2.6 is only defined for class definitions, and thus can only be used by instances.

Is there some equivalent for instrumenting get/set of globals?

I'm trying to speed up the importing of a module which interacts with the host system, and as such has to perform some expensive probing of the host. The results of the (expensive) probe are stored in a module global that is initialized at import time; so I'm trying to delay the initialization until absolutely required.

Please, no comments about globals being evil. I know what they are and when to use them.

My current plan is to create a global instance that uses descriptors, and move all my current globals into the attributes of this instance. I expect this will work; I'm just asking if there's another way.

Comment: It is possible (though I really would not recommend it) to subclass `module`, add the required descriptors, instantiate the subclass, and replace the current module's `sys.modules` entry with the new instance, all within the module's own file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My current plan is to create a global instance that uses descriptors, and move all my current globals into the attributes of this instance. I expect this will work; I'm just asking if there's another way.

That's precisely what I would do.  There is no equivalent to descriptors outside of classes.

The other option, which I have also sometimes used, would be to use a function instead of a variable name, something like this:

```
_expensive_to_compute = None
def get_expensive_to_compute():
    global _expensive_to_compute
    if _expensive_to_compute is None:
        _expensive_to_compute = do_computation()
    return _expensive_to_compute
```

If you already have a `@memoize` decorator defined somewhere, you can simplify the above considerably.

Comment: I suspected this would be the case. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, this link gives a pretty cool method to implement.  The only caveat is you'd have to execute your code using eval/exec/execfile.

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2011-March/009657.html

```
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self, mapping):
        self.mapping = mapping
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        value = self.mapping[key]
        if hasattr(value, '__get__'):
            print('Invoking descriptor on', key)
            return value.__get__(key)
        print('Getting', key)
        return value
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.mapping[key] = value

class Property:
    def __init__(self, getter):
        self.getter = getter
    def __get__(self, key):
        return self.getter(key)

if __name__ == '__main__':   
    md = MyDict({})
    md['x'] = 10
    md['_y'] = 20
    md['y'] = Property(lambda key: md['_'+key])
    print(eval('x+y+1', {}, md))
```

While a little cumbersome, I thought this was very cool.